# Find missing calendar weeks in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking for a SQL statement that outputs missing calendar weeks based on a table. Here is a short example. We are using MySQL. I dropped all the irrelevant columns.

```
+------+--------------+
| Year | CalendarWeek |
+------+--------------+
| 2012 |            1 |
| 2012 |            5 |
| 2012 |            8 |
| 2012 |            9 |
| 2012 |           51 |
| 2013 |            2 |
+------+--------------+
```

What I am trying to get:

```
+------+--------------+
| Year | CalendarWeek |
+------+--------------+
| 2012 |            2 |
| 2012 |            3 |
| 2012 |            4 |
| 2012 |            6 |
| 2012 |            7 |
| 2012 |           10 |
|  ... |          ... |
| 2012 |           50 |
| 2012 |           52 |
| 2013 |            1 |
+------+--------------+
```

I added the dots to shorten the output.

**Further background:** The columns in each row are computed via some logic in Java. If we create a new row, lets say for the current calendar week, we have to check if we need to fill gaps. Its a simple routine. Is there a row for the previous week? Yes? Fine we are done. Otherwise compute the value for the previous week, insert it and check the week before that. The one and only do-while-loop in the whole program.

This apparently fails if we start with a table that has more than one gap. In this case we have to run through all the calendar weeks for every year and check for missing rows. Takes some time.

**tl;dr** I am trying to reduce roundtrips to the database with a shortcut.

Comment: Good point! I ignored this case in the question. We manually add the 53 week.